# Map Object containing an other object using java reflection

Tags: java, mysql, reflection, orm

I try to map an object in my database.
It works fine for simple type like int, string ect... However i got a problem about a class containing an other object.

For example i got a class order :

```
public class order
{
  int id;
  Client c;

 public int getId();
 public void setId(int id);
}
```

and a class client :

```
public class Client
{
 int id;
 //some stuff like name ect and getter/setter...
}
```

I would like to map order by getting client id.

The problem is that when i try to get the package name of field Client it return me java.lang (package of field class...)

```
field.getType().getClass().getPackage().getName().compareTo("fr.javatp.model") == 0
```

I don't know why it doesn't return the type Client...

Any clue ?

this is code :

```
   public void insertObject(Object instance) throws SQLException,
        SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException,
        InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
        IntrospectionException, InvocationTargetException
{
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    this.type = instance.getClass();
    this.query = createInsertQuery();
    try
    {
        try 
        {
            connection = this.getConnexion();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        int i = 0;
        Class clazz;
        for (Field field : type.getDeclaredFields())
        {
            System.out.println("PACKAGE NAME : " + field.getType().getClass().getPackage().getName());

            if (field.getType().getClass().getPackage().getName().compareTo("fr.javatp.model") == 0)
                clazz = field.getType();
            PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(
                    field.getName(), type);
            Method method = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
            Object value = method.invoke(instance);
            preparedStatement.setObject(++i, value);
        }
        preparedStatement.addBatch();
        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.close();
        preparedStatement.close();
    }

}
```

and create Insert query code :

private String createInsertQuery()
    {

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("INSERT INTO ");
    sb.append(type.getSimpleName());
    sb.append("(");
    sb.append(this.getCol(false));
    sb.append(")");
    sb.append(" VALUES (");
    sb.append(this.getCol(true));
    sb.append(")");
    System.out.println("QUERY TO SEND : " + sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

and get Col code :

```
 private String getCol(boolean usePlaceHolders)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (Field f : this.type.getDeclaredFields())
    {
//      System.out.println("PACKAGE NAME : " + f.getType().getClass().getName());

        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            sb.append(",");

        if (usePlaceHolders)
            sb.append("?");
        else if (f.getType().getClass().getPackage().getName().compareTo("fr") == 0)
            {
                sb.append(f.getName() + ".id");
            }
        else
            sb.append(f.getName());
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: We need code to reproduce this. Shouldn't be hard to provide an MVCE.

Comment: I get  the right name of the package by removing getClass but still i can't access to getId method of client class

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this expression:

```
field.getType().getClass().getPackage()
```

Field.getType() returns the Class object of the field you are interested in. By calling getClass() on it, you are getting the class object of Class, which is java.lang.Class.class. So instead just use

```
field.getType().getPackage()
```

Have you thought about using an existing ORM instead of reinventing the wheel?